# How to catch a notification while cypress is waiting for page loading?

Tags: cypress

I need to assert notification about successfully finished action but I faced a problem which could not be resolved upon the test execution. Steps to reproduce:

1. Press Save button.
2. The page starts reloading.
3. Cypress starts waiting for finish page reloading.
4. The notification comes up but the page is still reloading and the test is paused.
5. The notification has gone while the page is still reloading.
6. At last the page is successfully reloaded.
7. Test starts working but assertion failed because the notification has gone.
   Is there any way to catch the notification while the page is being reloaded?

Comment: I would suggest you to try the waituntil npm package and identify an element in step 4 to wait until it is visible to then continue.

Comment: I am afraid that since the page starts reloading on step 2 any other command can't be executed before reloading is finished so waitUntil will start after reloading when the notification is vanished